# Compare columns of Pandas dataframe for equality to produce True/False, even NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe that are supposed to be identical. Each column has many NaN values. I would like to compare the columns, producing a 3rd column containing True / False values; *True* when the columns match, *False* when they do not.

This is what I have tried:

```
df['new_column'] = (df['column_one'] == df['column_two'])
```

The above works for the numbers, but not the NaN values.

I know I could replace the NaNs with a value that doesn't make sense to be in each row (for my data this could be -9999), and then remove it later when I'm ready to echo out the comparison results, however I was wondering if there was a more pythonic method I was overlooking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you could just use the [`equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html) method:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column_one'].equals(df['column_two'])
```

It is a batteries included approach, and will work no matter the `dtype` or the content of the cells. You can also put it in a loop, if you want.

Comment: What would be the best way to achieve this if 'new_column' needs to be populated based on multiple columns.

eg. df['new_column'] = df['column_one_x'].eq(df['column_one_y']) & df['column_two_x'].eq(df['column_two_y']) & df['column_thr_x'].eq(df['column_thr_y'])

Comment: Your example looks quite decent to me. Use it!

Comment: **`.equals()` returns a scalar**, so how does this answer the question? OP's result should be a vector, no? Or at least, maybe OP ultimately wants a scalar, but assigning it to a new column doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, Pandas does not consider NaNs different in element-wise equality and inequality comparison methods. While it does when comparing entire Pandas objects (Series, DataFrame, Panel).

> NaN values are considered different (i.e. NaN != NaN). - [source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

**Element-wise equality assertion [`.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html#pandas.DataFrame.eq)**

Compare the values of 2 columns for each row individually. This will return a Series of assertions.

*Option 1*: Chain the [`.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html#pandas.DataFrame.eq) method with [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```py
df['new_column'] = df['column_one'].fillna('-').eq(df['column_two'].fillna('-'))
```

Option 2: Replace the NaN assertions afterwards using [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html).

```py
df['new_column'] = df['column_one'].eq(df['column_two'])
df.loc[test['column_one'].isna() & test['column_two'].isna(),'new_column'] = True
```

Note that both options are non-destructive regarding the source data in *column_one* and *column_two*. It is also worth having a look at the [working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) guide in the Pandas docs.

**Object-wise equality assertion [`.equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)**

Compare Pandas objects (Series, DataFrame, Panel) as a whole, interpreting all rows and their order as a single value. This will return a single boolean value (scalar).

```
df['column_one'].equals(df['column_two'])
```

Comment: Note - the 'see also' sections in the links above mention some other methods to work with (strict) inequalities which might prove useful but are outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Wrong. .eq gives NaN!=NaN which fails the main requirement in OPs question.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson - Sorry, I read over the NaN value requirement. Find my updated post above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop like below and it works irrespective of whether your dataframe contains NANs or not as long as both the columns are having same format

```
def Check(df):
   if df['column_one']== df['column_two']:
      return "True"
   else:
      return "False" 

df['result'] = df.apply(Check, axis=1)
df
```

Comment: I see you're new - Please add a description to your code answers. Without the description, even if your code works fine, the answer is not very useful ^^

Comment: The truth value of an array is ambiguous; the if statement will likely error. Also, bool is a more natural return type than str, which would make the if statement redundant.

Comment: This is totally wrong. **NaNs don't compare equal**, as mentioned in the question. Secondly, everything else here is a bad imitation of OP's code; there's no need to use a function with `apply`, and returning strings is wrong - you should return bools. I don't see any redeeming qualities here so I'm voting to delete.

Comment: @user2561747 The parameter called `df` is actually being passed a `Series` representing a row, so that `if` won't error, but as I wrote above, the result will be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Working also for None values.

```
df['are_equal'] = df['a'].eq(df_f['b'])
```

result df:

[image]

Comment: `None` is not `NaN`. Pandas also considers it *missing*, but that's the only thing they have in common.